# Approximations to unbounded operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

In what sense, if any, can we construct an unbounded operator as a limit of an unbounded sequence of bounded operators?

A matrix representation of an algebra of raising and lowering operators, for example, is often displayed, in effect, as the limit of an unbounded sequence of bounded matrix operators, but in what sense is the limit *close* to the raising and lowering operators?

Edit: By "raising and lowering operators", I mean an algebra generated by $a^\dagger$ and $a$ that satisfies the commutation relation $[a,a^\dagger]=1$. If someone answers the specific question of the second paragraph, I hope I'll be able to reconstruct some kind of answer to the more abstract question of the first paragraph from that.

Comment: This question is too general.  Could you start over and focus on raising/lowering operators if that is your interest?  Can you describe, possibly with references/context what you mean by raising and lowering operators.

Comment: It's a large field, [for example](https://www.google.ca/search?q=operator+convergence+strong+weak+resolvent).

Comment: Thanks, @KeithMcClary. That focused my attention nicely. AFAICT, the limit of the usual unbounded sequence of bounded matrices that is given in physics textbooks converges in the *weak operator topology*, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology#Weak-star_operator_topology

Comment: I am guessing that this concept could be useful to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affiliated_operator

Answer (score 1):

For operators that have well defined resolvents (eg. self-adjoint, M-sectorial, operators with discrete spectra) you can work with various types of convergence of the resolvents (norm, strong, weak). The raising and lowering operators are not nice. You can work with $a + a^\dagger$ or $i(a - a^\dagger)$.